# Asking for password when there is no password

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

I have a machine in AWS EC2 platform. Its a linux platform, with the user named root having no password,

Now I have to setup, ssh key authentication on this machine, For that firstly, I installed cygwin, then I followed the following steps :

```
 1. ssh-keygen -t dsa -f ~/.ssh/<key name> -C "root@<ip>"
 2. cat ~/.ssh/<key name>.pub | ssh  root@<ip> "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Now, when I do this, it asks for password, but I never setup any password on the user **root**.

Also if I does not supply password, it says access denied!!!

Where is the problem?

Comment: Are you running into this error trying to add a new key? There is a key set when you launch your instance.

Comment: that key set I used, I want to add more ssh keys so that each user of that machine will get different ssh key...

Comment: In your ssh command, you are not specify the key to connect with using -i. You need to use your original key to connect before you can add more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the permissions on your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` they need to be `600` and also on the `~/.ssh` directory, they need to be `700`.

Also you can run your sash client with the `-vvv` option to get debug information.

Comment: Good answer but I was stuck at different blocker, anyways thanks did not know that this too is required....
:D